# How to get more animation effects to Powerpoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2007, slideshow

Currently, I am working with a presentation in MS Powerpoint, I have about 80+ slides in it and I found that the available Animation effects aren't sufficient for me, I have done a search in Microsoft website for them, but the search turned up with solutions for Office 365.

Do anyone know where to get them?

Comment: Just FYI, most animation effects detract from a presentation, as does using many different ones in a presentation.  It's one thing if you're trying to distract people from a poor presentation.  But if you actually have information to convey, focus on the content.  You will have failed if what people remember is the animation rather than the message.  If you use animation, keep it consistent and subtle.

Comment: Hopefully can create and play custom animation effects during your presentation.