# Download Templates for PowerPoint - How?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, templates

I am currently trying to find new templates for my PowerPoint presentation (Office 2007). So I was directed to:

https://templates.office.com/en-us/templates-for-PowerPoint

But there it seems I cannot download anything. It only says "Open in PowerPoint Online". So I am slightly confused. Where can I obtain new template?

Comment: [Similar](http://superuser.com/questions/889460/how-to-get-more-animation-effects-to-powerpoint) question, but no answer.

Comment: Would you care to inform me when you find a solution?

Comment: I am almost 100% positive Microsoft has support listing templates on its website for Office 2007.  If you want templates you will have to find them hosted somewhere else other than Office.com

Comment: Can get many templates hosted for free on many other sites for presentation.

Comment: @RogUE: In Office 2010 and 2013 you can preview, download and use templates right from the New File dialog. For older versions the answer given below should work (you'll need to be signed in of course to use PPT Online).

Comment: @User451885 make sure you have Hotmail account then login to download.

Answer (score 1):

Open in powerpoint online , Go to File , Save As , Download a Copy , and now continue your work in the downloaded file . Some things might be missing due to the incompatibility, but you'll be fine with the product.

Comment: +1 All the other later answer does is add screenshots to illustrate this one.

Comment: yeah it will be interesting to see who gets the green checkmark

Comment: The OP's an unregistered user who was last seen around half an hour after you posted your answer, so I doubt he's going to return and pick either one. That's often the case though and can't really be helped since the system doesn't allow anyone else to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

GoTo:  https://templates.office.com/en-us/templates-for-PowerPoint

[image]

Next open online

[image]

Sign in with Hotmail or live

[image]

Continue

[image]

GoTo - File - SaveAs

[image]

Than Download Copy to your computer.